# Conditional Redirection

Tags: javascript

```
<a href="/delete/<?php echo $prod_name; ?>" onClick="dropItem()">delete</a>
```

Now is it true that only if the function dropItem return true will the page be redirected to the url given in the href attribute?
 **If not then can anyone suggest any method to implement this kind of  thing. i.e only when the java script returns true the page redirection happens.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return true or false from within the onclick:

```
onclick="return dropItem();"
```

this will indeed stop default link behaviour when `false` is returned. Only exception: If `dropItem()` caused an error. In that case, default link behaviour will apply (i.e. the user will be redirected.)

Comment: @ayush accepting his answer and vote up would be nice way to thank him